# Difference between nodes and children

Tags: dart

The below code worked fine with me:

```
var q = theQty.shadowRoot.children[1].shadowRoot.children[0];
```

while the below code gave me an error "There is no such getter 'shadowRoot' in 'Node'" :

```
var q = theQty.shadowRoot.nodes[1].shadowRoot.nodes[0];
```

I could not understand the difference between using nodes(index) or using children(index), any thought?

Comment: Are these warnings in the IDE or runtime exceptions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `children` collection is of type `Element`, which has a `shadowRoot` property, whereas `nodes` is a collection of its base class `Node`. It's possible that in most cases these are the same (though Checked mode in Dartium would still throw), as there are only a small number of other classes (like `Document`, `DocumentFragment`) that extend `Node` but are not `Element`.

Answer (score 3):

The main difference is that `nodes` will give you ALL children of an element. While `children` will give you only children of type `element`. `nodes` will also include comments and textnodes - for example.

A small JavaScript example:

```
var span = document.createElement('span');
span.appendChild(document.createElement('span'));
span.appendChild(document.createTextNode('Test'));
console.log(span.childNodes.length, span.children.length)
```

Will return 2 1.

Comment: as per your explanation  Node is element children plus others, but in my case, children corked while nodes did not!

Comment: This is totally normal because children[1] returns the 1st CHILD and not node. I guess there are next nodes in between. Just print out all children and nodes. You cannot use the same index for both children and nodes in general.